# No output with gulp-htmltidy

Tags: html, gulp, tidy, htmltidy

I want to use tidy with gulp. But if I put it in the stream, I get no output, every single piece of html-code will be dropped. If I remove the pipe, I get the html. Do you have any clue?

My Gulp:

```
gulp.task('html', function () {
    return gulp.src(source.html)
      .pipe(plumber())
      .pipe(jade())
      .pipe(htmltidy({
        hideComments : true,
        indent       : true
      }))
     .pipe(gulp.dest(destination.html))
});
```

If I remove all options from htmltidy, I get also no output. And before you ask: Yes, the variable `htmltidy` is set correctly `htmltidy= require('gulp-htmltidy')`

I have to use htmltidy because gulp-inline-css remove trailing slashes in self-closing tags. The document can not be html5 because we use it for mailings.

Comment: Is there a reason for using `gulp-htmltidy`? You can get the exact same result htmltidy would give you, setting the `pretty` parameter for the `gulp-jade` task: `.pipe(jade({ pretty: true })`

Comment: I have to use htmltidy because gulp-inline-css remove trailing slashes in self-closing tags. The document can not be html5 because we use it for mailings.

Comment: Any chance you're on OS X? Had the same issue receiving an empty file, since there's an issue with htmltidy2 where there was no working executable of `tidy5`. Opened PR: [ayhankuru/htmltidy2#1](https://github.com/ayhankuru/htmltidy2/pull/1)

Comment: have you find any solution to this ? I also have the same problem. Empty file if I use htmltidy